# Embed Listview in Treeview in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

How to embed a listview in to each nodes of the Treeview?
I am new to the WPF.

Comment: Look into [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) and [data templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Most often, you bind an ObservableCollection to the ItemSource of the TreeView. The class you bind to should incorporate two things, at least: Children (which is an ObservableCollection of the same class, to form a hierarchy and ListItems, which holds the items you wish to display under each node.

Define the following HierarchicalDataTemplate in Window.Resources (or UserControl.Resources, depending on where you work):

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="TreeTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}"
    IsExpanded>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListItems}"/> // or ListBox, which is probably more fitting
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

And the TreeView:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Your_Node_List_Here}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TreeTemplate}"/>
```